# Date Time Error in Sql

Tags: sql-server, casting

I've stored `StartDate` as datatype `nvarchar` in the format **yyyy/mm/dd** in my database. When I try to cast it to a `datetime`, I'm getting `Arithematic Flow Error.`

What's this Error? I've tried both `cast` and `convert` method but error is still thrown.

Here's my code:

```
cast(Start_Date as datetime) &&
convert(datetime,Start_Date,103 )
```

Comment: Actually i was not the culprit.Our pjt leader designed the database and i was forced to do so.Now datatype cannot be modified to datetime

Comment: Can you post a **complete** and repeatable SQL statement that actually gives the "arithmetic flow error"?

Comment: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Comment: If it's a date/time - store it as a `DATETIME`!! Otherwise you'll always have hassle and problems...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

`103` is `dd/mm/yyyy` so this will fail

```
declare @S varchar(10)
set @S = '2012/03/31'
select convert(datetime, @S, 103)
```

Try this instead

```
select convert(datetime, replace(@S, '/', ''), 112)
```

Your cast will fail if you have [SET DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx?ppud=4) as `dmy`.

```
set dateformat dmy

declare @S varchar(10)
set @S = '2012/03/31'
select cast(@S as datetime)
```

But will work just fine if you use `ymd` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @TestDateValue nvarchar(50)
set @TestDateValue = '2012/12/03'
select cast(@TestDateValue as datetime) as NewTestDateTime
```

Your code should work. I have just given an example here. Can you post the string that you are trying to convert. COuld be something to with it.